# How do I change the default '- Any -' option in views exposed filter?

Tags: 8, views

I have exposed filters in a view as select lists. How can I change the text for the default filter option of "- Any -"? In previous versions it was suggested to use a preprocess function like this:

```
if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form') {
      foreach ($form['FIELDNAME']['#options'] as $key => &$option) {
        if ($key === 'All') {
          $option = 'All';
        }
      }
    }
```

But in Drupal 8, instead of a modifiable key/value, it is stuck inside a protected class.

```
protected string -> string(7) "- Any -"
```

How can I modify this?

Note: I also tried Better Exposed Filters, but it is unable to rewrite the "- Any -" option.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to install the *Better exposed Filters* module, and maybe you don't want to code your template function. In this case you can go with either CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css) or jQuery (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870707/use-jquery-to-change-value-of-a-label).

Answer (score 8):

Better Exposed Filters works for me well in my Drupal 8. On *Better Exposed Filters > Settings > More Options > Rewrite results*, replace *- Any -* with the text you want, following this format: *- Any -|your replacement*.

Comment: Correct, but there is currently a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2822916) for an issue causing an error if you add any replacements.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible for grouped date fields

Answer (score 6):

The *All* key contains an translatable object, so it works as before. You just need to use code similar to the following one.

```php
$form['field_your_field']['#options']['All'] = t('Text you want');
```

Comment: Where do I place this line? In theme-settings.php?

Comment: In the hook_form_alter() function in your .theme file or custom module

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way to do this at the theme level. You could change '- Any -' to a particular value or some other variable.

Copy select.html.twig to your theme. Modify the template to check if option.label equals '- Any -' and if so change it to whatever you'd like. In the code below it is set to the value for the filter's label.

```
{% elseif option.type == 'option' %}
  {# custom if statement #}
  {% if option.label == '- Any -' %} 
    {% set option = option|merge({ 'label': element['#title'] }) %}
  {%  endif %}
  <option value="{{ option.value }}"{{ option.selected ? ' selected="selected"' }}>{{ option.label }}</option>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205403) pointed me in the right direction.
The merge filter didn't work for me. I don't know what I was doing wrong, so I used a simpler solution.

```
{% elseif option.type == 'option' %}
  {# custom if statement #}
  {% if option.label == '- Any -' %}
    <option value="{{ option.value }}"{{ option.selected ? ' selected="selected"' }}>- All -</option>
  {% else %}
    <option value="{{ option.value }}"{{ option.selected ? ' selected="selected"' }}>{{ option.label }}</option>
  {%  endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This solution works for me best because Better Exposed Filters doesn't have a rewrite option for grouped date fields.

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you can use select.html.twig in your custom theme with the following code.

```
{% spaceless %}
  {% if input_group %}
    <div class="input-group">
  {% endif %}

  {% if prefix %}
    {{ prefix }}
  {% endif %}

  {# Browsers do not recognize pseudo :after selectors, we must create a wrapper
   # around the select element to style it properly.
   # @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/21103542
   #}
  {% if not attributes.offsetExists('multiple') %}
  <div class="select-wrapper">
  {% endif %}
  {% set classes = ['form-control'] %}
  <select{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% for option in options %}
      {% if option.type == 'optgroup' %}
        <optgroup label="{{ option.label }}">
          {% for sub_option in option.options %}
            <option
              value="{{ sub_option.value }}"{{ sub_option.selected ? ' selected="selected"' }}>{{ sub_option.label }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </optgroup>
      {% elseif option.type == 'option' %}
        {# custom if statement #}
        {% if option.label == '- Any -' %}
          {% set option = option|merge({ 'label': '-All-' }) %}
        {% endif %}
        <option value="{{ option.value }}"{{ option.selected ? ' selected="selected"' }}>{{ option.label }}</option>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  {% if not attributes.offsetExists('multiple') %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}

  {% if suffix %}
    {{ suffix }}
  {% endif %}

  {% if input_group %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in your *themename.theme* file in your theme directory. This worked for me.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function nameofwebtheme_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id']=='views-exposed-form-what-s-on-page-1') {
    $form['field_date_range_value']['#options']['All'] = t('Text you want');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on *Better exposed Filters: Settings*, you will see a *Rewrite filter options* drop-down under *More options for...*.

Add *- Any -|All* or change it to anything you need. This works.